# How to add any text/script before </body>

Tags: plugin, content

Is there any content plugin that let me to put any text/code/script before closing `</body>` tag? If there is no such plugin, is there any documentation about how to create that kind of plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plugin code

```
<?php
// no direct access
defined('JPATH_BASE') or die;

class plgSystemMyplugin extends JPlugin
{
    function onAfterRender()
    {
        $app = JFactory::getApplication();

        if ($app->getName() != 'site') {
            return true;
        }

        $buffer = JFactory::getApplication()->getBody();

        $insert = 'insertthis';
        $buffer= str_ireplace('</body>',$insert.'</body>',$buffer);

        JFactory::getApplication()->setBody($buffer);

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: There are `appendBody()` and `prependBody()` methods worth reading up on.

Comment: https://api.joomla.org/cms-2.5/classes/JApplicationWeb.html#method_prependBody thanks @mickmackusa

Answer (score 2):

Why use a Joomla plugin? You can just do the following:

- Add a position in the template (e.g. in your `templates/template-name/index.php`) just before the closing `</body>` tag. Let's call this position `code`.
- Create a Custom HTML module (now called a Custom module), and add your script code to it, and then assign it to the `code` position and to the appropriate pages.
- Remove the enclosing div tag added to the Custom HTML module as described [here](http://www.itoctopus.com/how-to-remove-the-div-tag-from-custom-html-modules).

I don't think in your scenario you should really use a plugin as a module will suffice and will do exactly what you need to do (it is also a cleaner approach, since plugins add to the overhead of all the pages).

Comment: I use the modal extensively, sometimes in one article I need to put 2-3 modals, between paragraphs

Comment: What do you mean by modal?

Comment: It's the bootstrap modals. Anyway, I actually know some workarounds for the modal issue, but in this question, I'm looking for answer that is telling me whether it's possible to add acript/code before closing body tag or not, and if it's possible, how to do that. I will update the question

Comment: The answer that I provided explains how to add script before a closing body tag. You can use a custom HTML module to do that. Maybe I missed something though, I'll wait for you to update your question.

Comment: I want to achieve the same thing @itoctopus and the reason I can't use your method is because I am creating a module that I want to be able to distribute to others without them having to take that step.