# What is the correct way to use appendBody

Tags: joomla-api

I'm trying to understand `appendBody`

First of all append would seem like it comes after the `</body>` but I assume it can only mean after the contents of the body.  And prepend before the contents of the body not before `<body>` e.g. in the head.

https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JResponse.html#method_appendBody

My code looks like this:

```
use Joomla\CMS\Application\WebApplication;

$thingToAppend = "<div>I am Eoin</div>";
appendBody::_($thingToAppend);
```

But when I use it I receive this error.

> Error: Class 'appendBody' not found: Class 'appendBody' not found

What am I doing wrong?

After Mick's advice I tried:

```
WebApplication::appendBody($callpage_io__script);
```

> But I got using $this when not in object context

So then I tried

```
$callpage_io__script = "<div>I am Eoin</div>";
$appendBody = new WebApplication;
$appendBody->appendBody($callpage_io__script);
```

Which did not error, but also did not produce any HTML

Comment: Syntax error. `appendBody()` is a method, not a class. 
 https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/Joomla.Application.AbstractWebApplication.html#method_appendBody  A static method name would come after two colons.  `JApplicationWeb::appendBody()`  See comments under question at https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/323/12352 and [this relevant answer with commentary from GeorgeWilson](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/26304/12352).

Comment: Ah ha.  But then I have tried. `WebApplication::appendBody($callpage_io__script);
` but then I get the error `Error: Using $this when not in object context: Using $this when not in object context`

Comment: So then I tried another route (updated question).  No PHP error, but still no HTML either.  Could it be because I am doing this in a module and it is arrive after the body has been created?  So I would need to do this as a plugin instead? @mickmackusa

Comment: If your intention is to add content before `</body>` tag, see  answer https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/18551/12652.

Comment: Are you saying appendBody doesn't add it there?  Surely it doesn't add it between `<body>` and `<HTML>` or after `<HTML>`

Comment: @Sharky the reason I am not adding it that way is because it uses a plugin and I have a really simple module so I didn't want to create a package just for this purpose.

Comment: This method is working as intended. It appends content to the entire application response body. It is not document aware and not limited to HTML output. For adding content before `</body>` tag, a method would need to be added to `Joomla\CMS\Document\HtmlDocument`. Until then, using a plugin is the correct way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please note that `JResponse::appendBody()` is a depreciated method.

If you still want to use it, you can call it in a system plugin against the `onAfterRender` event.

Here is an example -

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

class PlgSystemMyPlugin extends JPlugin
{
    /**
     * Application object.
     *
     * @var    JApplicationCms
     */
    protected $app;
    
    
    public function onAfterRender()
    {
        if (!$this->app->isClient('site'))
        {
            return;
        }
        
        $this->app->appendBody('<div>I am Eoin</div>');
    }
}
```

This will add the "I am Eoin" string at end of the body i.e. after the  tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-gb" dir="ltr">
<head>

</head>
<body>

</body>
</html><div>I am Eoin</div>
```

If you want to append your string before the  closing tag then you need to use a custom plugin with the following codes -

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

class PlgSystemMyPlugin extends JPlugin
{
    /**
     * Application object.
     *
     * @var    JApplicationCms
     */
    protected $app;
    
    
    public function onAfterRender()
    {
        $doc = $this->app->getDocument();
        
        if (!$this->app->isClient('site') || $doc->getType() !== 'html')
        {
            return;
        }
        
        $buffer        = $this->app->getBody();
        $thingToAppend = '<div>I am Eoin</div>';
        $buffer        = str_replace('</body>', $thingToAppend . '</body>', $buffer);
        
        // Use the replaced HTML body.
        $this->app->setBody($buffer);
    }
}
```

Comment: So `appendBody()` is actually adding content after `</html>` instead of just before `</body>`?  That's rather unintuitive.

Comment: There's no way anyone would ever want that @mickmackusa.  That can't be right. @jumbo if you see my code I'm not actually using JResponse, I used the class mapping for J4 so I used `Joomla\CMS\Application\WebApplication;` but well done for mentioning it for others to see.  What if I want to use this in a module?  Is that possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5958040/2943403  Also, I do not recommend using `str_replace()` or `preg_replace()` to modify an html document because they are vulnerable to over-matching and are both DOM-ignorant.  As a simple case, if you have an article that contains the characters `</body>` (perhaps while explaining how to write htmls tags in a programming/tutorial article), then these php functions will make two replacements instead of one.  My professional advice is to use a dom parsing technique to modify a html document.

Comment: @mickmackusa This shouldn't be a problem because in-content tags would have to be escaped on HTML pages. It's not valid to have more than 1 body tag anyways.

Comment: @mickmackusa It should not be a problem. Even core Joomla! System - SEF plugin uses preg_replace. Moreover, dom parser will not work here. It will break the HTML in most of the sites.  You can try it yourself. Example: dom parser does not support empty HTML elements.

Comment: @Jumbo 1. Just because you see something in Joomla core doesn't mean it is good/best -- Joomla is in constant development. I have found many things that I consider not good / not best in the core. 2. There are settings that can be used to make DomDocument forgive some invalid HTML markup.  I suspect that Joomla is _forced_ to implement `preg_replace()` so that it can support bad/invalid html content from its users.  Within a given person's project (where html validity can be ensured), a legitimate dom parser is ideal.

Comment: @mickmackusa HTML5 is not supported by DocDocument. It also does not support custom HTML tags. I tried it many times in past, but always faced problems using it. This is the reason why you will also find many HTML parser classes in development and they all use regex. Yes, DomDocument can be a lot faster and safer method if it supports HTML5 and custom HTML tags.

Comment: In all of the DomDocument answers that I have posted on Stack Overflow, I've never encountered any problems while parsing valid html5 documents. Here is a simple example that doesn't break: https://3v4l.org/s35iK  Yes, all legitimate parser are leveraging regex, but they are far more sophisticated than mere regex.  Often DomDocument is slower than simple regex solutions but that is because dom parsers are, again, more sophisticated.  The reason to use a dom parser is never speed, it is always for quality output.  If a parser fails for any specific case, then sure use regex.

Comment: @Jumbo I am happy to learn something new if you can provide a demo of valid html5 that domdocument fails to parse.  I don't mean for this to become adversarial.  This back-and-forth will educate one of us or both of us (not to mention researchers).  After some thought, I guess my demo link didn't have a full html document (although it did have a html5 tag in it -- it was just the first one that I found). I'd still like to see a valid html5 document fail.

Comment: @mickmackusa Okay. I will try to create an example for you. :)